# XML reading in android

Tags: android

2008 
     2009 
     2010 
     2011

I have above information in a xml file in android. I want to read & store these data in a array or hash map. Please help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) article describes how to use DOM parser, SAX parser and XML Pull parser in your Android application. Choose either one of them to get your job done.

Answer (score 0):

[Use a sax parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)